# How do I make the TriangleWithException object?

Tags: java, object, try-catch

I'm doing some homework here. Here is my code so far. I have made a Triangle class, a GeometricObject class, and an IllegialTriangleException class. The homework says to create a TriangleWithException object passing the values, 1.5, 2, and 3 to the constructor, and another object with the values 1, 2, and 3. Here is my code so far:

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public Triangle() {
        this.side1 = 1;
        this.side2 = 1;
        this.side3 = 1;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return side1 + side2 + side3;
    }
    public double getSide1(){
        return side1;
    }
    public double getSide2(){
        return side2;
    }
    public double getSide3(){
        return side3;
    }
    public void setSide1() {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }
    public void setSide2() {
        this.side2 = side2;
    }
    public void setSide3() {
        this.side3 = side3;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle: Side 1 = " + side1 + " Side 2 = " + side2 + " Side 3 = " + side3;
    }
}
```

```
class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {
    private double side = 1.0;
    public IllegalTriangleException(double side) {
        super(side + " is larger than other two combined");
    }
    public double getSide1() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String color = "White";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    public GeometricObject() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Created on " + dateCreated + "\n color: " + color + " and filled ";
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out here? It needs to have try and catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the Constructor of your new class the possibility of throwing your exception. Just give the sides as a paramater, and you can check it with If's and throw your exception if needed.

```
public TriangleWithException(double side1, double side2, double side3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
      if (side1 > side2 + side3){
         throw new IllegalTriangleException(side1)
      }
      // Add if's for other sides

      this.side1 = side1;
      this.side2 = side2;
      this.side3 = side3;
    }
```

Your main then can contain the following code:

```
try{
    TriangleWithException triangle1 = new TriangleWithException(1.0,2.0,3.0);
} catch (Exception e){
     // Your triangle is invalid
}
```

Comment: I added the code, but it wouldn't compile because the TriangleWithException method is missing a return statement. You want me to make a new class named TriangleWithException?

Comment: Since your assignment says: "The homework says to create a TriangleWithException object", you indeed need a class TriangleWithException

Comment: And it would be smart to let this new class, extend your Triangle class!